# Custom TableCell Border

Tags: java, javafx-8

If you look in modena.css you can see how the border of the default TableCell is specified:

```
.table-cell {
    ...
    -fx-border-color: transparent -fx-table-cell-border-color transparent transparent;
    ...
}
```

As you can see the border is transparent apart from the right side that has the color specified by -fx-table-cell-border-color.

I would like the border on the right side to have two different colours. -fx-table-cell-border-color for all the pixels apart from the very bottom pixel that I would like to be red.

Is there anyway to specify that a border side is made up of more than one colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
.table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: transparent 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, -fx-table-cell-border-color 95%, 
                                   red 95%) 
        transparent 
        transparent;
}
```

Note the 95%, depending on the height of the rows you can increase it to 95%+.

I've included this (scaled) pic of two tables, one with regular css (left), one with this css (right). The red pixel is just at the corner.

[image: scaled view of table row]

Comment: That is the sort of thing I was thinking about but because of the linear gradient I can never get the bottom pixel to be exactly red and the one above to be exactly -fx-table-cell-border-color no matter which percentage I use.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to modify the gradient. Now it has only two pure colors. Also, the pic shows the result on the right table.